# Method calls from threads with a specific delay

Tags: c#, multithreading, thread-synchronization

I need to synchronize a method call, so that threads can call this method after a 500ms sleep. I have 10 threads that may run at the same time, so that simply introducing `Thread.Sleep(500)` does not help. How can I achieve this in the simplest way? What can you suggest?

```
_pool = new Semaphore(0, 10);
_pool.Release(10);
...
pool.WaitOne();

Thread thr = new Thread(WorkerThread);
t.Start(param);
...
public static void WorkerThread(object parameterData)
{
    ...
    MethodToBeSynced();
    ...
    _pool.Release();
}
```

Comment: I don't understand your requirement, sorry.  Why can you not put the Sleep(500) at the top of the method code?

Comment: Suppose two threads start at the same time. If they come to this `Sleep(500)` line at the same time, they both will wait for 500ms and will eventually call my method at the same time. However, what I want is, if a thread is executing this method, the other thread should wait for 500ms and start execution.(This should be valid for the rest of the threads of course, if they try to invoke the method)

Comment: so the methond can only be executed once every 500 ms? Sounds weird, doesn't it?

Comment: Hmm.. I would probably queue up the requests to one thread that has a loop with  the queue wait, does method, fires a callback in the request, Sleep(500) and loop around.  Maybe that's just me :)

Comment: @Arno - weird, but not unbelievably so.  Comms with crappy, slow peripherals springs to mind.

Comment: The method does weird things inside it and it is completely out of my control. All I know is, I should not call this method concurrently by several threads. If one thread is executing this method, then the other thread should wait for a while and start execution, without the need to wait the other thread to complete the execution of the method.

Comment: Oh, +1 just for 'The method does weird things inside it'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you know the number of concurrent threads (And given they start approx. the same time), you could use a `Barrier` with a `PostPhaseAction` delegate.

```
 var barrier = new Barrier(10, (x) => Thread.Sleep(500));
```

The barrier waits until 10 threads are at a certain code point and once that happens, each thread will sleep for 500 ms and then continues.

If the exact number of threads is unknown, you could specify a wait timeout to not block infinite.

```
// Waits up until N threads are at the barrier or after the timeout has elapsed.
 _barrier.SignalAndWait(500);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use System.Threading.Timer

You can give it a callback function as well as the interval when to call this function.